# G++ Not found, I've already tried 3 different compilers

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, mingw, jgrasp

I can compile C code no problem using MinGW but for some reason I can't compile C++. I already tried other compilers, cygnus and cygwin. 
I'm using JGrasp. Here's the error feed:

```
 ----jGRASP wedge2 error: command "g++" not found.
 ----   This command must be in the current working directory
 ----   or on the current PATH to use this function.
 ----   PATH is ";C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
                 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live 
                 C:\windows\system32;
                 C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;
                 C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
                 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared; 
                 C:\mingw\bin;  
                 C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin; 
                 C:\cygwin\bin;".
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: Do you know what directory g++ resides in?

Comment: Did you install g++? IIRC, by default MinGW only installs the C compiler - you'll have to tick a checkbox during installation.

Comment: it's found in the bin folders of either one of the three compilers

Comment: @Pubby No I didn't, is there a way to do it now that I've already installed it?

Comment: @Ceelos I dunno. Restart the installation and *only* tick the g++ checkbox? Reinstall maybe?

Comment: Is the path to g++ in the system ``PATH`` variable? Can you run g++ directly?

Comment: @gongzhitaao mingw/bin is in PATH, therefore g++ should be in path

Comment: can you run g++ from cmd.exe?

Comment: is it oddly named in the mingw/bin folder? `mingw32-g++`? `x86_w64_ming32_x86_w64_g++`? or something like that? have a look through that folder

Comment: Why not the most obvious compiler: Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: @Scones, I tried it that way too, didn't work. I redid a fresh instal of mingw this time including C++.

Comment: @Pubby if you place that as an answer I suppose I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I instructed in the comments, you need to install g++ with the MinGW installer. By default, MinGW only installs the C compiler.

To get g++, tick a checkbox during installation.

Answer (score 9):

You also can use `mingw-get` commandline installer: **`mingw-get install g++`**

It can be useful to execute `mingw-get update` before.

**Documentation:** http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started (section *Command Line Interface Installer*)