# Where is G++in MinGW install?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, gcc, mingw

I installed MinGW and set the variable PATH. Then g++ in the terminal worked only ONCE, then the terminal does not recognize g++ only gcc, as you can see:
[image]

I tried to reinstall it, but it did not work. Still the g++.exe file is missing.
And when I try to install it, the terminal says I already installed it, like this:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [G++ Not found, I've already tried 3 different compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795864/g-not-found-ive-already-tried-3-different-compilers)

Comment: I tryed these already.

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing again.

Comment: I tryed it three times already.

Comment: If you install gcc and g++ the compiler should be in the MinGW installation dir under `C:\MinGW\bin` (default). There you find a `gcc.exe` and `g++.exe`.

Comment: The problem is that there is no such a file g++.exe just disapeard to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just type echo $PATH then you should have your g++ executable file on that path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already have the solution, my antivirus deleted g++.exe very time when i installed it.